# how find resonance in extrasolar planet?

Tags: planets, data-analysis, resonance, exoplanets

I make this program, i have a 2xN matrix in which the columns are the ID of planets and their period, the rows are the number of planets, for istance something like that:

```
1 0.44
1 0.8
1 0.9
2 0.9
2 1.2
3 2.0
3 3.0
```

The trick to change from one system of planet to the other is to rename all the planets of a system with the same number and the planets of other system with another number so, i can be able to change the resonance condition from one system to another one.

The program is simple:

1) read the file and save the columns and rows numbers, 2) create and save a matrix of col*row objects, 3) save as a vector the name and period of planets, 4) start the cycle:

`for r=1,row` <--- THIS MUST READ all the file
`if (difference in name = 0.)` then start the resonance find criterion 
`for l = 0,4` (number of planet in each system: THIS MUST BE MODIFIED !!)

```
for i = 1,5 
for j =1,5
```

`if (i*period(l)-j*period(l+1) eq 0)` then write on file <- RESONANCE CONDITION !!!

```
end if
   end for
   end for
   else write a separation between the first set and second set of planets !
   end if
```

This is the IDL code i wrote: pro resfind

```
file = "data.dat"
rows =File_Lines(file) ; per le righe
openr,lun,file,/Get_lun ; per le colonne
line=""
readf,lun,line
cols = n_elements(StrSplit(line, /RegEx, /extract))

openr,1,"data.dat" 
 data = dblarr(cols,rows)
 readf,1,data
close,1


name = data(0,*)
period = data(1,*)

openw,2,"find.dat"
 for r = 0, rows-2 DO BEGIN ;
        if (name(r)-name(r+1) EQ 0) then begin 
                for l = 0,rows-2 do begin 
                         for j = 1,4 do begin
                                 for i = 1,4 do begin

                                           if (abs(i*period(l)-j*period(l+1)) EQ 0.) then begin 
                                           printf,2, 'i resonance:', i , ' j resonance:',j,' planet ID:',l,' planet ID:',l+1
                                           endif
                                 endfor 
                         endfor
                endfor
        endif else begin
        printf,2, '                                                    ' 
endfor


close,2

end
```

PROBLEMS:

1) i can't understand how to eliminate the multiply of resonance (2:4, 3:6 and so on);

2) in the second for loop (the one with the planet) the number of planets must be change every time but i don't understand how to change this.

And this is the f90 version of the code:

```
program resfind
    implicit none
    integer::i,j,k,s,n
    real*8,allocatable::ID(:),period(:)

    open(10,file='data.dat')
    n=0
        DO
          READ(10,*,END=100)
          n=n+1
        END DO

 100     continue
        rewind(10)

    allocate(ID(n),period(n))
s=0
    do s=1, n
        read(10,*) ID(s),period(s)
    end do
    open(20,file='find90.dat')

! do r = 0, rows-2 DO BEGIN ;
!        if (name(r)-name(r+1) EQ 0) then begin 


i=0
j=0
k=0
 do i = 1,n-1 
  do j = 1,5 
   do k = 1,5  
     if (abs(j*period(i)-k*period(i+1)).EQ.0.0) then   
     print*, i,j,k
    write(20,*) 'j resonance:', j , ' k resonance:',k,' planet ID:',i,' planet ID:',i+1
    end if
   end do
  end do
 end do

 close(20)

end program resfind
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like it has to do with physics, it seems more like you're looking for help debugging your Fortran code.

Comment: this is my guess to find resonances, i put the codes here to understand if someone have different idea on the if condition to check for resonances .

Comment: This question would probably fit on the up and coming [mathematical modeling SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling) when it opens up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming and a specific program rather than physics or a specific physics concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to say, but assuming you're just looking for period resonances of the form $a:b$ where $1\leq a,b\leq 5$, the following 4 lines of Mathematica code using your example list of extrasolar periods should suffice:

```
A = {0.44, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0};
n = Length[A];
d = 0.05;
ResonanceMatrix = MatrixForm[Table[DeleteCases[Tally[Flatten[Table[If[Abs[k A[[i]] - l A[[j]]] < Sqrt[k l] d, l/k, "NR"], {k,5}, {l, 5}]]][[All, 1]], "NR"], {i, n}, {j, n}]]
```

Output:

> $$\text{ResonanceMatrix}=\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  \{1\} & \{\} & \left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\} & \left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\} & \{\} & \{\} & \{\} \\
>  \{\} & \{1\} & \{\} & \{\} & \left\{\frac{2}{3}\right\} & \left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\} & \{\} \\
>  \{2\} & \{\} & \{1\} & \{1\} & \left\{\frac{3}{4}\right\} & \{\} & \{\} \\
>  \{2\} & \{\} & \{1\} & \{1\} & \left\{\frac{3}{4}\right\} & \{\} & \{\} \\
>  \{\} & \left\{\frac{3}{2}\right\} & \left\{\frac{4}{3}\right\} & \left\{\frac{4}{3}\right\} & \{1\} & \left\{\frac{3}{5}\right\} &
>    \left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\} \\
>  \{\} & \left\{\frac{5}{2}\right\} & \{\} & \{\} & \left\{\frac{5}{3}\right\} & \{1\} & \left\{\frac{2}{3}\right\} \\
>  \{\} & \{\} & \{\} & \{\} & \left\{\frac{5}{2}\right\} & \left\{\frac{3}{2}\right\} & \{1\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

For example, the $(2,5)$ entry is $\frac{2}{3}$, indicating that there is a $2:3$-resonance between planet 2 and planet 5. The diagonal entries are all 1, since every planet has a $1:1$-resonance with itself. The parameter $d$ controls the tolerance when deciding if resonance occurs. Duplicates of the form $\frac{na}{nb}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are automatically deleted.